# How can i make an HTA window dependent on another?

Tags: hta

I need to make an `.hta` window dependent on the other `.hta` window. So, basically window A cannot be closed without window B being close first. I have the two window right next to each other and they act as one window when settings is click (it basically displays a popout or extension of the first window that has options for the application).

Second window is executed by:

```
Sub Settings()
  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objShell.Run "Launcher-Settings.hta"
End Sub
```

And the button is:

```
<input type="button" value="Settings" name="MSG-Button" id="LauncherSettings1" class="LauncherSetting1" onClick="Settings()" />
```

Both windows are close by:

```
<input type="button" value="<<    Close" name="CloseButton" id="CloseButton" class="CloseButton" onClick="javascript:Window.close()" />
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. `onload` events are not cancelable even in HTA. You could close both windows at the same time though. How to do it, depends on which kind of windows you have, and how are they opened.

Comment: The first window is opened buy executing Launcher Plus.hta and the second window in opened using onClick of a button. I will add the script in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in my comment, it should be "`unload` events are not cancelable...".

You can force window B to be closed just before closing A using WMI, something like this:

```
top.onbeforeunload = function () {
    var wmiLocator = new ActiveXObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator'),
        wmiService = wmiLocator.ConnectServer('.', 'root\\CIMV2'),
        htaProcesses = new Enumerator(wmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where name = 'mshta.exe'")),
        htas = [], n;
    while (!htaProcesses.atEnd()) {
        if (htaProcesses.item().CommandLine.indexOf('Launcher-Settings.hta') > -1) {
            htas.push(htaProcesses.item());
        }
        htaProcesses.moveNext();
    }
    for (n = 0; n < htas.length; n++) {
        htas[n].Terminate();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is this and how do i use it?

Comment: I am sort of new to all of this programming thing, I am more used to basic web design

Comment: Just put the function to a script within your main window, it will automatically close window B, when the main window is closed.