# Using a WScript.shell activeX to execute a command line in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, shell, unix

I am trying to execute a command line using shell script by taking the example of below code

```
function callShellApp() {
    var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
    objShell.run('"c:\menu.exe"');
}
```

According to my required the objShell.run should be in synchronous mode until unless that happens i should allow the user to navigate the screen .Is there a way we can do that to maintain that .

Answer (score 0):

Afaik a fully synchronous execution of external source is not possible with JS, here's a snippet which has a "semi-synchronous" call:

```
objShell.Run('"c:\\menu.exe"', 1, true);
// JS after the line above is not executed until menu.exe has been terminated
```

Notice also escaped backslash. Though the JS will wait, the page itself is responsive. To prevent interaction between page and user, you can do somthing like this:

```
top.addEventListener('focusin', function () {
    objShell.AppActivate(apptitle); // apptitle === the title of the window wherein `menu.exe` is running
});
```

Unfortenately even this won't prevent timed functions to be executed.

This will also cause troubles when closing the page before `menu.exe` has finished. Plese see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387578/1169519), how to close your app if this happens.

Comment: Uhh... You've to set correct `CurrentDirectory`, then it works, if the file exists.